# Match Regex except Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a text like this:

```
22 <a data-event="event:noted:tasks" class="btn btn-default show-if-closed" title="Noted Tasks">
25 <a data-event="event:until-today" class="btn btn-default show-if-closed" title="Until Today">
28 <a data-event="event:until-one-week" class="btn btn-default show-if-closed" title="Until One Week">
31 <a data-event="event:until-one-month" class="btn btn-default show-if-closed" title="Until One Month">
```

Now I want to replace the entire text except the string that is inside the title-Tag.

After replacing the text I would like to get lines like this:

```
Noted Tasks
Until Today
Until One Week
Until One Month
```

What Regex-Pattern do I need to match the text except the title-Values? The pattern should be universal, not limited to a-Tags

Comment: use a HTML parser, select all the a and get `title` attribute value

Comment: I would like to do this with an editor like gedit.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 1 "title=" in a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
^.*?title="([^"]*)".*$
```

and replace with `\1`. In that way, the entire line is replaced with the desired info.

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ep3dem/2).

---

Please note that it is better to use proper HTML parsers to... ahem... parse HTML.

---

> The pattern should be universal, not limited to a-Tags

Considering that the word `title` can appear anywhere on a web page (normal text, class names, keywords...), only a dedicated HTML parser will help you in the long run.

Comment: Groups 1 & 3 are useless.

Comment: That's exactly why I wrote `and replace \1 and \3 with nothing`. OP was looking for a search and replace/delete the useless data, rather than finding the useful data.

Comment: That's not the point, I said you don't need to capture the beginning and the end of the line, it is very ineficient and slow down the process.

Comment: Normally, a search for `title="([^"]*)"` should be enough, capturing `\1`. But OP requested something different. Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: Find: `^.*?title="([^"]*)".*$` Replace: `$1` is much more efficient, only 1 capture group.

Comment: But in this case, `$1` is the useful data, which needs to be kept - not replaced. How can one replace what is outside of `$1` with nothing, in order to get only `$1` in the end?

Comment: This replaces the whole line by the content of group 1. That's what is wanted.

Comment: Bingo! :) The lonely LED finally flickered in my head. Thanks for taking me out of the narrow box where I was.